# Oregon SNS topic isn't visible in route53 health cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created an SNS topic in OR region and would like assign SNS topic to Route53 health check cloudwatch alarm. But I don't see the SNS topic in the list. I was able to see VA region SNS topic, but not OR regions SNS topic. Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is there
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233637
It's a matter of regions